# How to access private fields from parent class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am testing out various combinations to build a super class and a subclass and I realized there is no way to access the private fields from the parent class when I do the following:

```
abstract class Ball{
    private int size;
    protected Ball(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }    
    public abstract void setSize(int size);  
    public abstract int getSize();           
}

class SoccerBall extends Ball
{
    public SoccerBall(int size){
        super(size);
    }
    @Override
    public void setSize(int size){this.size = size;}//size not inherited
    @Override
    public int getSize(){return size;}              //size not inherited    
}
```

I know private fields won't be inherited to the subclass. The only way (probably the only way other than reflection) to access it is to use getter and setter.

So my questions:

(**Q1**) If I want to keep the field in the parent class as private and not protected. Should I ***not*** make the getter and setter abstract in order to make the private field accessible to its child?

(**Q2**) If I were to make the field (size) private, how should I implement my getter and setter to make the private field accessible by the subclasses?

Comment: Why do you even think about exposing abstract get/set methods for private property?

Comment: @JakubKubrynski Do you mean in this case, it is more suitable for `size` to be protected? I set it as private because I have seen it in many occasions where parent class holding fields which are private. Several SO solution also mention it is fine, but have to access it with getter and setter. But now I am thinking, how are we supposed to access private fields with getters and setters?

Comment: In this case, there wouldn't be a need for abstracting the getter/setter since an abstraction means you're simply expecting the implementing class to create and follow the method signatures to be compliant.  The implementing class should be responsible for defining the "size" variable internally to itself.  Else since you're wanting to define how the getter/setter works (ie. store the value in a variable), you should just provide it as concrete methods.  Implementors can then override at their own convenience.

Comment: Guys I think I see it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to keep the field in the parent class as private and not protected. Should I not make the getter and setter abstract in order to make the private field accessible to its child?

Yes, since the field is private and can only be accessed if a getter and setter is defined in the parent class. The getter and setter should not be declared as abstract.

> If I were to make the field (size) private, how should I implement my getter and setter to make the private field accessible by the subclasses?

Just implement a normal getter and setter in the parent class where the private field resides.

```
abstract class Ball{
    private int size;
    protected Ball(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }    
    protected void setSize(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }
    protected int getSize(){
        return size;
    }          
}
```

**The subclass**

```
class SoccerBall extends Ball{
    public SoccerBall(int size){
        super(size);
    }       
    @Override
    public void setSize(int size){
        super.setSize(size);
    }
    @Override
    public int getSize(){
        return super.getSize();
    }               
}
```

Comment: **Remarks:** I have figured out this is one way to make it work. Some kind souls can give me some comments whether this is the actual way to do it? Or there exist some other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access the value directly, change the access level of size to "protected". This way, it will will be mostly encapsulated except when accessed by subclasses.

Comment: So where would you implement the getter and setter?

Comment: Actually, in reality, the you should make size protected. This way, you cannot access it externally, except for within subclasses. I did not realize at first that the getSize and setSize methods were abstract :P

Comment: The getters and setters need not necessary be abstract. I just want someone to show me the proper way to access private fields from parent class.

Comment: You cannot do such without using a method accessible to the subclass or by just changing the variable's access level.